# Flutter - Error: Couldn't infer type parameter 'T'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on Flutter 2.2.1 (channel stable). I reccently changed my SDK's environment from 2.7.0 to 2.12.0 in order to add plugins and I got a lot of errors in my code. One of them is about a list of radio buttons.

My code :

```
ListView.builder(
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemCount: languages.length,
    itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
      return RadioListTile(
        title: Row(
          children: [
            Image.asset(
              'icons/flags/png/${languages[index]['flag']}.png',
              package: 'country_icons',
              height: 16,
            ),
            Text('  ' + languages[index]['language']),
          ],
        ),
        value: languages[index]['code'],
        groupValue: widget.languageChosen,
        onChanged: (_languageSelected) {
          setState(() {
            _languageChosen = _languageSelected;
            widget.onLanguageChange!(_languageChosen);
          });
        },
      );
    }),
```

The error is about 'RadioListTile' and the message is:

> Couldn't infer type parameter 'T'.
>
> Tried to infer 'dynamic' for 'T' which doesn't work:   Parameter
> 'onChanged' declared as     'void Function(T?)?'
> but argument is 'void Function(Object?)'. The type 'dynamic' was inferred from:   Parameter 'value'      declared as
> 'T'
> but argument is 'dynamic'.   Parameter 'groupValue' declared as     'T?'
> but argument is 'dynamic'.
>
> Consider passing explicit type argument(s) to the generic.

I got another error about '_languageSelected' at the line `_languageChosen = _languageSelected;` The error is:

> A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type
> 'String'. Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the
> right-hand type to 'String'.

But I don't know if both errors are linked.

Comment: You have to give a `type` to the `RadioListTile` like `RadioListTile<String>()` or `RadioListTile<YourLanguageItem>()`, check this: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RadioListTile-class.html

Comment: Thanks, it's working (I guess, I've one more error to fix before to test). And I fix the second one with ```_languageChosen = _languageSelected.toString();```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct code:

```
ListView.builder(
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemCount: languages.length,
    itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
      return RadioListTile<String>(
        title: Row(
          children: [
            Image.asset(
              'icons/flags/png/${languages[index]['flag']}.png',
              package: 'country_icons',
              height: 16,
            ),
            Text('  ' + languages[index]['language']),
          ],
        ),
        value: languages[index]['code'],
        groupValue: widget.languageChosen,
        onChanged: (_languageSelected) {
          setState(() {
            _languageChosen = _languageSelected.toString();
            widget.onLanguageChange!(_languageChosen);
          });
        },
      );
    }),
```

Answer (score 27):

It was a simple fix for me I forget to specifically declare the type of my values in my widget.

Error

```
DropdownButton()
```

No Error

```
DropdownButton<String>()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Radio<dynamic>(
  value: paymentMode[0]['id'],
  groupValue: _selectedPaymentMode,
  onChanged: (value) {
    _canSubmit = false;
    _selectDoctor = false;
    _selectedPaymentMode = value;
    setState(() {});
  },
),
```

`<String>` or `<dynamic>` or As your Datatype